# Find out what view inside has been clicked in a custom ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment in Android that has two elements:

- A TextView containing a "Task" (R.id.taskView).
- A TextView containing the employee that has that task assigned.

If the user clicks on the Task name it will display the task info in another fragment. But if the user clicks on the employee's name the other fragment will instead display that employee's info.

I have uploaded an image to help understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYbk8.jpg

I am using a custom adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View currentView = convertView;
        if (currentView == null) {
            currentView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bLoton_habitacion, parent, false);
        }
        setOnclickListeners(currentView, position);
        return currentView;
}

private void setOnclickListeners(View currentView, int position) {
    TextView taskView = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.taskView);
    taskView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TASK LISTING", "TASK VIEW CLICKED");
        }
    });
}
```

This works as expected. If the user clicks on the taskView the message "TASK VIEW CLICKED" is displayed.

But the problem is that I need to know what position of the ListFragment was clicked; onClick method will not "see" what element was clicked.

Is there a way to get the position of the element the user clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the position argument of your setOnclickListeners-method a *final* int and then use that parameter in `onClick()`